# Why the content of the pure IEnumerable is invisible for WPF DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, ienumerable

Let's say I have a datagrid with itemsource binded to property Collection, which is for example IEnumerable. Of course I wrote appropriate getter and setter for it.

Now, when I assign to this property (Collection) just IEnumerable (as the result of some method), like:

```
Collection = FooMethod(); // FooMethod returns IEnumerable<MyClass>
```

datagrid will display empty rows. The count of the rows will match the count of the Collection.

But when I force conversion, like this:

```
Collection = FooMethodp().ToArray(); // forced fetching data
```

datagrid will show all rows with content now.

So what stops datagrid from showing data in case of pure IEnumerable? It has to iterate over a collection so fetching occurs anyway.

### edits

Just for the record. MyClass is this:

```
public class ErrorsIndicators
{
    public double Min { get; set; }
    public double Max { get; set; }
    public double Avg { get; set; }
}
```

and FooMethod returns (return yield) several items. So, nothing fancy here.

Comment: Which data grid? Does the same thing occur with a ListBox, for example?

Comment: The datagrid, there is only one kind in WPF. The ListBox has only one column, so the mechanism is slightly different than in datagrid.

Comment: There are plenty of third party DataGrids, and the one in WPF only made it into 4.0, so I had to ask. Number of columns has nothing to do with iterating over the data, but use a `ListView` if you like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to say without seeing the implementation of `FooMethod()`, but I suspect it is returning something that implements `IEnumerable<T>` but not anything further (such as `ICollection<T>` or `IList<T>`). That being the case, it appears as though the DataGrid is unable to dynamically determine the column names and you need to tell it yourself via the `DataGrid.Columns` property.

Here's a simple repro I put together.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**:

```
namespace DataGridTest
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Windows;

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Customers = this.GetCustomers();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        private IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomers()
        {
            yield return new Customer() { Name = "first" };
            yield return new Customer() { Name = "second" };
            yield return new Customer() { Name = "third" };
        }

        public IEnumerable<Customer> Customers
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**:

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Window>
```

If you remove the `DataGrid.Columns` from the XAML, it displays three empty rows. So it appears as though it's not the enumerating of the data source that is broken when the source only implements `IEnumerable<T>`, but rather the automatic column creation.

Comment: Thank you very much. However I think it classifies as a bug -- after all item class (as long as it has properties) is valid and datagrid should detect it.

Comment: I agree. I can't account for the behavior - I can only testify to it. Perhaps you could file a report on Connect. I suspect it would be very low priority though.

Comment: Sure thing, my other reports were closed as wontfix so I would be not surprised of even worse outcome.