# .Net 6 WPF - My DataGrid is not being populated

Tags: c#, wpf

My DataGrid is blank when page loads, what am I doing wrong?

Code-behind:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace TestingIfEnumerableWillBind
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var key1 = new WidgetA { Id = 1, Key = 52 };
            var key2 = new WidgetA { Id = 1, Key = 102 };
            var key3 = new WidgetA { Id = 1, Key = 152 };
            IEnumerable<WidgetA> list = Enumerable.Empty<WidgetA>();
            list.Append(key1);
            list.Append(key2);
            list.Append(key3);

            DataGrid1.ItemsSource = list;
        }
    }

    public class WidgetA
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Key { get; set; }
        public string ValueToGet { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<StackPanel>
    <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid1" AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545169/why-the-content-of-the-pure-ienumerable-is-invisible-for-wpf-datagrid

Comment: Instead of `Enumerable.Empty`, use `List<T>` and call Add instead of Append.

Comment: Did you add your Loaded event to the xaml? Loaded="Window_Loaded"

Comment: Turns out I needed `list=list.Append(key1)` can someone help me undstand why this is?